# How to make the simpliest http post request possible in Angular?

Tags: angular, httpclient

Struggling to get a simple http post working, here is the code I have:

```
var config = {
      headers : {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    }

    var data = {
      "gender":"M"
    };

    this.http.post<any>("http://localhost:8080/rest/endpoint", JSON.stringify(data), config)
    .subscribe(
        (val) => {
            console.log("POST call successful value returned in body", 
                        val);
        },
        response => {
            console.log("POST call in error", response);
        },
        () => {
            console.log("The POST observable is now completed.");
        }
    );
  }
```

This request is called by a click in a button, and when executed I can see in the Chrome network tab that a OPTIONS http request have been executed which returned GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS and then the POST was executed, but it does not seem to have sent the body data I intended it to send, below is what I see in the network tab:

```
**General**
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/rest/endpoint
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: [::1]:8080
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
**Response Headers:**
Allow: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Content-Length: 0
Date: Mon, 22 Apr 2019 11:18:51 GMT
**Request Headers:**
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,pt-BR;q=0.8,pt;q=0.7
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:8080
Origin: http://localhost:4200
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.62 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: You do not need to stringify the data if you are using `HttpClient`, pass in `data` directly (as an object).

Comment: I did try the object directly without strigfying it, same result.

Comment: boreq, I thought CORS wouldn't be a problem as per both angular and API are running localli, no? My intention is to deploy angular and the API in different subdomains of the same domain, would that work?

Comment: It works after allowing CORS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular the best practice is to maintain service and component separately.
If using angular cli you can generate a new service by  **ng g service serviceName** 
Add/Include service to your appmodule(root module) in providers array to make it globally accessible.You can make service local by including it in specific component.ts file too.

I will provide you with basic outlook/working.
In service.ts import necessary modules.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'; 
import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class serviceName {
  private url = `http://localhost:8080/rest/endpoint`
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  //method 
  public newGender(data): Observable<any> {
    const params = new HttpParams()
      .set('gender', data.gender)
    return this.http.post(`${this.url}`, params)
  }
```

In component.ts

```
constructor(service:serviceName){}
//subscribe to service now
//method
public methodName=()=>{
   let data = {
      "gender":"M"
    };
this.service.newGender(data).susbcribe(
response=>{
//your response
})
} //end method (call this method if needed)
```

Comment: I have separated the call into a service as suggested but that did not make any difference, thanks anyway I can see it is better organized now.

Comment: Have you imported httpclientmodule in root module?

Comment: Yes it is imported, I'm starting to thing it is indeed a CORS issue, as linked by boreq in his comment in the question, but not sure yet.

Comment: have you set allowedCorsOrigin = "*"   in backend?

Comment: Trying to get that configured at the moment, it was not, but the error did not look like a CORS issue at first.

Comment: I did make the server to allow CORS requests but still not working, I find weird that the content type seems not being set correctly in the request, Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Seems as if it was set but without value, I don't see the application/json anywhere.

Comment: Instead of allowing CORS backend-side you can just run local proxy which will allow you to call your API endpoints like `https://localhost:4300/api/endpoint`, and passthrough it to any server you want.
https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server